# Fixing python packages mis-installed by `sudo pip` / `sudo pip3`

Tags: python, linux, pip, debian

Python packages should **not** normally be installed with **`sudo pip`**, nor **`sudo pip3`**[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342241/1483904), but in the past I think I installed some with `sudo`, before I knew better.

What's the best way to now recover from this mistake?

Can I somehow find and uninstall these `sudo` installed packages, or is there a way to start all over?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+remove+all+packages

Comment: `sudo pip freeze | xargs sudo pip uninstall -y`

Comment: The suggested "already answered here" Q/A does not mention sudo, so how can it be an answer to my question?  In fact it explicitly refers to his virtual environments, so this would not be system packages at all.  Will someone please re-open my question, and stop this abusive closing of similar but different questions.

Comment: `sudo` is the least interesting part here. "*Can I somehow find and uninstall these … packages…?*" — this is the main part and the linked dup clearly answers that.

Comment: @phd, In my title line I put the word `sudo` twice.  Then in the first sentence `sudo` 3 times, and once again a `sudo` in the last sentence.  Furthermore, if you cared to look at the footnote, you would also see that this is all about `sudo`.  Yes, I really do want to know how `sudo` plays with installing and uninstalling.  I'm really quite baffled that you say that "`sudo` is the least interesting part here.", when it is about 90% of what I was trying to ask about.

Comment: Here lives a pretty good set of answers to this question, as well as a general tutorial about where things get installed and uninstalled from in various situations:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58619629/1483904  Now I'll test it out.  Thank you.