# AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name'

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, https, python-requests

In python, on a Ubuntu server, I am trying to get the `requests` library to make https requests, like so:

```
import requests
requests.post("https://example.com")
```

At first, I got the following:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.

After following the advice in this question: [InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent), I have now upgraded my warning to the following error:

> AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute
>   'set_tlsext_host_name'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fix for me was the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-openssl
sudo pip install pyopenssl
```

Comment: I needed to `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` before installing pyopenssl

Answer (score 3):

This was able to get the python working on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS for me.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip build-essential libffi-dev
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip setuptools && sudo -H pip install --upgrade pyopenssl
```

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading pip was what was needed in my case.

Answer (score 2):

On RedHat:

```
sudo yum remove pyOpenSSL
sudo pip install pyopenssl
```