# InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available on iPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, tweepy, urllib3

I am trying to fetch some tweets using tweepy in my iPython notebook. I have the following code snippet for it -

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("abc", "xzy")
auth.set_access_token("asd", "zxc")
api = tweepy.API(auth)
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
```

I got the following error -

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
```

InsecurePlatformWarning

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent) SO question and update from 2.7.8 to 2.7.10. I am still getting this error. However when I run this piece of code on my terminal it works fine. So I am not understanding what is the issue with iPython.

Comment: Did you install the extra dependencies? `pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1`

Comment: @shazow - unfortunately I am still getting that error. I tried the command that you have suggested and I got an output saying that all the requirements are already satisfied.