# Unable to pip install MySQL-python in Virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, pip, virtualenv

Attempting to pip install MySQL-python in a virtual environment, also getting an error trying to pip install it outside of  a virtual environment.

I've read similar questions and tried all the proposed solutions, but 1) none worked and 2) I don't really understand the cause of this still.  Could someone help me out?

Apologies in advance for the noobish question, I'm pretty new to this.

Here's the error:

> (env)ryans-air:outreach ryanfarley$ pip install MySQL-python
>   Collecting MySQL-python
>   /Users/ryanfarley/Desktop/outreach/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:90:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning   Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       sh: mysql_config: command not found
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 20, in 
>         File "/private/var/folders/fb/5pp5q35x541493ccjj7g0w580000gn/T/pip-build-BIQjaP/MySQL-python/setup.py",
>   line 17, in 
>           metadata, options = get_config()
>         File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
>           libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
>         File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
>           raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
>       EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> ```
>
> /private/var/folders/fb/5pp5q35x541493ccjj7g0w580000gn/T/pip-build-BIQjaP/MySQL-python

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent

Comment: @dan-klasson unfortunately that did not work :(

Comment: See if the answer here does the trick for you: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52548990/7305166](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52548990/7305166)

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL libraries have not been installed or cannot be found by pip when installing the package. The MySQL-python package will rely on MySQL libraries and executables (in the case of mysql_config) on your system.

See [pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5178292/2278723).