# Getting pygame running in docker

Tags: python, docker, pygame, tensorflow

I'm trying to get PyGame running in a docker (so I can eventually work with PyGame and TensorFlow in windows). But when I try run:

```
pip install pygame
```

I get back

```
root@03da78748024:~# pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame
```

Pip install does work with other packages, e.g. pybrain. Also is successfully installed on my windows machine. But I want to install it within docker so I can use it with TensorFlow.

Does anyone have any experience of getting pygame running in docker? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it's really old thread but I'm trying to create a pygame-windows docker... the source code would be very helpful, can you share?

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the security extras:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202163/1703772

Some questions:

- <strike>Can you pip install other packages?</strike>
- <strike>Is it just pygame that fails?</strike>
- Is installing a pip package locally a viable solution for you? https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-do-a-user-local-install-of-a-python-package

The fact that it reports no versions of pygame accessible is a red flag.
You could try installing using a windows installer: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads (from https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-do-a-user-local-install-of-a-python-package)

UPDATE:

From my non-exhaustive searching, `Windows` + `Docker` + `pip` to install `pygame` **will not work at this time.** Installing using a windows installer seems to be the accepted solution by many.

Here are some solutions you can try:

- Installing via `pip wheel` locally (64-bit and 32-bit wheels)

  - **Instructions**: https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/03/installing-the-windows-64-bit-version-of-pygame/
  - **Downloads**: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame
- Installing Pygame from a windows binary (32-bit only, `.msi`): http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
- If Docker is anything like Vagrant (uses vms as applications), you can bring in local wheel files as part of bringing up the application.
- Upload the wheels to PyPi and use pip to install that package, but then there are licensing issues you'd have to consider and abide by.

The current pygame on pypi is 1.7.1 and supports up to Windows 2000/NT: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygame/1.7.1? - perhaps your windows version is too new.

I hope this has answered your question.

Comment: Thanks, for getting back to me, I've edited my question to make some of it clearer. pip install of other stuff does work. Don't think I can do an install of the windows binaries into Docker?

Comment: @DanielSlater It seems possible, but difficult according to this google group for docker users using linux: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/twc786X3ChM Another forum states that they used the `.msi` version to get it working: https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3j1ks2/installing_pygame_via_pip_on_windows/ . I've searched around in the past 15 minutes on google and it seems that windows + docker + pygame does not work with `pip`.

Comment: @DanielSlater I have installed python 2.7.9 and Docker Toolbox 1.9.1f and trying to install pygame results in this message: `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pygame`. Pip packages that depend on pygame fail to install with the same message.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to do this. This is exactly where I got to when trying to do this.