# Pygame MIDI Playback in PaaS from Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, flask, audio, paas

**The Problem:**

I am currently deploying a Python Flask App using a Dockerfile on a PaaS (Heroku like). The User Story is as follows:

1. User Clicks 'Generate MIDI'
2. MIDI is generated and User can (on the same page):

- 1. 'Download MIDI' (currently works perfectly locally & PaaS deployment)
- 2. 'Playback MIDI; (only works on local Flask deployment)

I had some `NotImplemented`: no such file or dir... errors which have gone away since I added some install lines to my Dockerfile. Alas, I  am stuck at this **ALSA error**: 
`pygame.error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory`
I know **for certain** the file is a good directory as downloading proves the file exists and references the source. Locally, you can also see the file generate.

**The Context**:
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /appname

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
# Added to avoid NotImplemented errors
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq \
    libgtk2.0-dev \  
    libasound2 \
    alsa-tools \
    # Original Run Command
    && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \  # Doesn't work.

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "--app", "appname", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Here is a pertinent snippet of my Flask App:

```
from pygame import mixer

        if request.form.get('playback_midi') and MIDI_file:
            if 'Playback MIDI' in request.form['playback_midi']:
                mixer.init()  # <-- Here is where it fails
                mixer.music.load("temp_MIDI_File.mid")
                mixer.music.play()
```

The `"temp_MIDI_File.mid"` is used so that it is constantly overwritten without unique file names (that is handled elsewhere).
**What I've Tried:**
Currently, I'm working with these references:
[Run Apps Using Audio in a Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985714/run-apps-using-audio-in-a-docker-container)
[Getting pygame running in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498267/getting-pygame-running-in-docker)
I'm thinking the 'Run Apps Using Audio in a Docker Container' might have the solution in there, I'm just not sure if the same solution could possibly work in a PaaS context (as I'm not sure what audio device would possibly be usable in this cloud hosting scenario; or if I even have privileges to access it). I'm also open to using a different package besides Pygame. Thanks!

**Further Research:**
[Running Sound in a Container](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/wiki/Container-sound:-ALSA-or-Pulseaudio)
[Docker Container Audio](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Docker-Container-Audio/)
[Docker Tips - Play Audio in a Container (2022)](https://youtu.be/SF_WMBpQ0Qs)

[Maybe this is best handled in JS...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/how-to-play-audio)

**Leaving it for now...**
I was able to Use the html `<audio>` tag to generate audio successfully.
All of the controls work. This leads me to two complicated avenues I don't quite have time to pursue, but will put a pin in...

1. *Audio-Deviceless File Render* - Using the FluidSynth API, perhaps I could convert the MIDI to a WAV and play the audio using the html `audio` tags. `midi2audio` seemed like a pythonic way to approach this, but seems configured on using ALSA just like `pygame`. The FluidSynth API is coded in C, so I'm not sure how to bridge this.
2. *Specify the device to be used by ALSA in the container* - Perhaps I could specify --device in the Dockerfile to find the audio device and use a full Ubuntu image to launch it.

Comment: There is no point in adding tags to the title of the question.

Comment: Do those `pygame.mixer` calls run as part of the server code?  I'd expect the Heroku instance doesn't have usable audio hardware, Docker concerns aside.  That is, I don't think this setup will work if the browser and server are on different systems, even if containers aren't involved.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking, too @DavidMaze :( . I have a post in the PaaS forum (DigitalOcean) to see if I have any options. I was hoping I could docker run --device tags and use the server machine / host or something. Maybe I could make something work if create a Droplet / Virtual Machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Solution:**

Fortunately, there is an awesome html MIDI player that solved this issue:
[html-midi-player](https://cifkao.github.io/html-midi-player/)

Here is my Flask HTML Template Code:

```
{% if MIDI_playback %} 
    <midi-player
     src="{{  MIDI_playback }}"
     sound-font visualizer="#myPianoRollVisualizer">
    </midi-player>
    <midi-visualizer type="piano-roll" id="myPianoRollVisualizer"
     src="{{  MIDI_playback }}" style="color: white">
    </midi-visualizer>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/tone@14.7.58,npm/@magenta/music@1.23.1/es`6/core.js,npm/focus-visible@5,npm/html-midi-player@1.5.0">
    </script>
```

**An Important Note:**
Using the script within this Python Flask App, I ran into this CORS error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
> access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

My workaround was to specify a CORS configuration in local and production instances.