# Python pip install request[security] have error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

i have try to install request[security] pack with pip , but have some error occur, anyone know how to do , Thanks.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 220, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 601, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 397, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 372, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import msvc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/msvc.py", line 244, in <module>
    class PlatformInfo:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/msvc.py", line 253, in PlatformInfo
    current_cpu = safe_env['processor_architecture'].lower()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'processor_architecture'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent)

Comment: I have tried that solution , but not work,thanks

Comment: What version of Python do you have? I remember I saw similar error with Ubuntu 12.04, once I upgraded to 14.04 (ships with newer python), everything went well...