# RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to use keras in the LXPLUS cluster for CERN users.

For that I am using a CMSSW release that already has python installed, just missing install keras... but...

```js
$ python --version
Python 2.7...
$ pip install keras
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting keras
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading Keras-2.0.1.tar.gz (192kB)
    100% |################################| 192kB 847kB/s 
Collecting theano (from keras)
  Using cached Theano-0.8.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyyaml in /cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc493/external/py2-PyYAML/3.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from keras)
Collecting numpy>=1.7.1 (from theano->keras)
  Using cached numpy-1.12.0.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/user_number/pip-build-7YA1PY/numpy/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.")
    RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/user_number/pip-build-7YA1PY/numpy
$ pip --version
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```

I know there are many tutorials and solutions to these errors but none has been a clear or direct solution for my case.

1. PIP VERSION: How to change pip version 7.1.0 to 9.0.1? (In case it is useful for installing keras).
2. `InsecurePlatformWarning`: [InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent) (this does not help me solve it because the problem still appears...). Can you help me with this?
3. `raise RuntimeError`: Should I apparently use a CMSSW release with python version greater than 2.7?
4. Python location: To install keras should i run python from what location?

```js
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
or
/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc493/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_X_Y_Z/external/slc6_amd64_gcc493/bin/python (with "cmsenv")
```

Comment: you can upgrade `pip` with `pip install --upgrade pip` (to install system wide) or `pip install --user --upgrade pip` (to install it just for you). Beware combinations with virtualenv or conda might be desirable on the long run.

Comment: Not using cmssw myself, but are you sure you set up using cmssw correctly? i would suspect cmssw ships its own python through cvmfs, such that after a proper setup, $PATH is set such that `which python` returns some location on /cvmfs

Comment: @pseyfert - Curiously I have python 2.7.11 ($ python --version  :  Python 2.7.11) and pip 9.0.1 ($ pip --version  :  pip 9.0.1 from /user_area/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)). PIP version warning continues and new problem appears (DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6). How to solve this?

Comment: I wanted to correct this title, should be as it is in this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861163/installing-keras-on-lxplus-with-cmssw-release). Think I configured cmssw correctly ($ cmsrel CMSSW_X_Y_Z, $ cd CMSSW_X_Y_Z/src/, $ cmsenv) and so I have my own python ($ which python  :  /cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gccABC/cms/cmssw/CMSSW_X_Y_Z/external/slc6_amd64_gccABC/bin/python). I still have the same problems installing KERAS, any help?