# Vagrant Up: InsecurePlatformWarning

Tags: python, ssl, vagrant, pyopenssl

I'm trying to do `vagrant up` but keep running into this error:

```
==> default: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_billiard.so'
==> default: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
==> default:   InsecurePlatformWarning
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

I did install `urllib3[secure]` and built `cryptography` as the documentation says, but no luck with that.

Working from Ubuntu 16.04

Vagrant version --> 1.9.3

Just in case, VirtualBox version --> 5.1.20r114628

Also i'd rather avoid doing `sudo vagrant up` as I have read several times it is not recommended. I'm fairly new to this and don't want to mess up a lot.

**UPDATE:** i have already tried installing `requests[security]` as I read on a similar thread, but did not solve the issue...

**UPDATE:** also tried following this thread -->
 [InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent) but not working either

Comment: Did you try to resolve error you got `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`. After this you may get luck. Just a suggestion.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yeo, but that does not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade python modules

`sudo pip install pyOpenSSL cryptography idna certifi --upgrade
sudo pip install urllib3[secure] --upgrade
sudo pip install requests[security] --upgrade`