# SyntaxError: '<' operator not allowed in environment markers

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, pyinstaller

Under python 2.7, I want to install mock-2.0.0, and got the following error:

```
Marker evaluation failed, see the following error.  For more information see: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/compatibility.html#evaluate-marker
ERROR:root:Error parsing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbr/core.py", line 96, in pbr
    attrs = util.cfg_to_args(path, dist.script_args)
  File "/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbr/util.py", line 261, in cfg_to_args
    kwargs = setup_cfg_to_setup_kwargs(config, script_args)
  File "/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbr/util.py", line 455, in setup_cfg_to_setup_kwargs
    if pkg_resources.evaluate_marker('(%s)' % env_marker):
  File "/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1515, in evaluate_marker
    return cls.interpret(parser.expr(text).totuple(1)[1])
  File "/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1549, in interpret
    return op(nodelist)
  File "/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1463, in atom
    return cls.interpret(nodelist[2])
  File "/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1549, in interpret
    return op(nodelist)
  File "/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1484, in comparison
    raise SyntaxError(msg)
SyntaxError: '<' operator not allowed in environment markers
error in setup command: Error parsing /histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/Python_packages/mock-2.0.0/setup.cfg: SyntaxError: '<' operator not allowed in environment markers
```

After a while googling, I got the hints that this error was produced by older version of setuptools ([discussion 1](https://github.com/openaps/openaps/issues/95) and [discussion 2](https://blog.cloudhelix.io/resolving-the-syntaxerror-operator-not-allowed-in-environment-markers-error-on-centos-7-2636c36aecac)).

The content of setup.cfg file is:

```
[metadata]
name = mock
summary = Rolling backport of unittest.mock for all Pythons
home-page = https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock
description-file = README.rst
author = Testing Cabal
author-email = testing-in-python@lists.idyll.org
classifier = 
        Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
        Environment :: Console
        Intended Audience :: Developers
        License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License
        Operating System :: OS Independent
        Programming Language :: Python
        Programming Language :: Python :: 2
        Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
        Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
        Programming Language :: Python :: 3
        Programming Language :: Python :: 3.2
        Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3
        Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
        Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5
        Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython
        Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: Jython
        Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy
        Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries
        Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules
        Topic :: Software Development :: Testing
keyword = 
        testing, test, mock, mocking, unittest, patching, stubs, fakes, doubles

[extras]
test = 
        unittest2>=1.1.0
docs = 
        jinja2<2.7:python_version<"3.3" and python_version>="3"
        Pygments<2:python_version<"3.3" and python_version>="3"
        sphinx<1.3:python_version<"3.3" and python_version>="3"
        sphinx:python_version<"3" or python_version>="3.3"

[files]
packages = mock

[bdist_wheel]
universal = 1

[egg_info]
tag_build = 
tag_date = 0
tag_svn_revision = 0
```

However, After testing setuptools version 15.2, 27.3.0, 38.0.0 and the latest 40.2.0, the error remain. I have no idea how to debug this problem now.

All the installation of the python packages were performed using

`python setup.py install --prefix=/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/`

Thanks!

I have tried the following test

```
1. using pip
1.1 pip install  mock==2.0.0
/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting mock==2.0.0
/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mock==2.0.0 (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for mock==2.0.0

1.2 pip install mock
/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting mock
/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/histor/kang/yangpc/soft/Python/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0.dev0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mock (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for mock
```

This invoked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent), which I haven't found a solution.

**update**

This problem has been resolved by updating python from 2.7 to 2.7.15 and reinstall all the depended packages.

Thank you all!

Comment: It might help if you show the install command that you used.

Comment: Hi @BramVanroy, thank you for pointing out this lack of information, I have updated the content of the question and added the installation command.

Comment: @pengchy still not quite enough. You should show contents of `setup.cfg` in this case, as the error is coming from there.

Comment: more constructively: why do you install this way, as opposed to using `pip`? e.g., `pip install mock==2.0.0`

Comment: thank you @matejcik, I have updated the content.

Comment: thanks for the updates. please also try `pip install mock`, without the version specifier -- unless you actually need mock v2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 versions of python installed on my `centos 7.9`. `python2.7` and `python3.6.

`pip` threw me the above error `pip3` did succeed.

e.g.
`pip install mock` **## failed**.

`pip3 install mock` **##Succeeded**